# Visual Studio Xamarin iOS Storyboard - An Error Occured on the Designer Agent

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode-storyboard

When opening the *Main.storyboard* file on the Visual Studio, I got an error:

*Something went wrong.
An error occured on the Designer Agent.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Contents of C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Logs\14.0\iOSDesigner-9236.2017-01-15__09-14-29.log:
MDAddinsHash: c92d0626d347XXXXXXXXX*

I have all the requirements:

- Both Xamarin for Visual Studio (on Windows) and Xamarin Studio Community (on the Mac) are the latest version (updated at the same time recently). Both use Stable channel.
- The Visual Studio is connected to the Mac using Xamarin Mac Agent.
- iOS Developer and Provisioning Profiles are set correctly on the Mac. On the Keychain Access, I see that the iPhone Developer certificate is valid.

Here is the Xamarin full log file from the Visual Studio:

http://pastebin.com/11GURqGd

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have? Please make sure you are on the latest Xcode, currently 8.2.1